# ‘Drive somebody to’: Why with infinitive?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

We use ‘look forward to *+ gerund*’. [According to Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/look-forward-to) the use of gerund is due to the fact that ‘to’ is a preposition when following ‘look forward’ (as opposed to an infinitive marker).

At the same time ‘drive somebody to *(+ verb)*’ requires the verb to be an infinitive. [Cambridge itself](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drive) gives ‘violent behaviour […] drove her to leave home’ as an example.

Whenever ‘drive somebody to’ is followed by a noun, ‘to’ appears to be a preposition. [Cambridge on the same page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drive) lists ‘love has driven men and women to strange extremes.’ [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drive) mentions ‘into’ as an alternative preposition, as in ‘The recession […] drove them into bankruptcy.’

1. Is ‘to’ in ‘drive somebody to *(+ verb)*’ a preposition or an infinitive marker?
2. Assuming ‘to’ is a preposition: If the rule were to use gerund whenever ‘to’ is not an infinitive marker, wouldn’t we need to say ‘drive somebody to *+ gerund*’, as for example ‘violent behaviour drove her to leaving home?’ Wouldn’t that be consistent with ‘look forward to *+ gerund*?’
3. Long story short: **Why is ‘drive somebody to’ followed by an infinitive and not a gerund as e.g. ‘look forward to?’**

Comment: Don't worry so much!  It's going to drive you to drink!!

Answer (score 2):

First . . . this is not a rule: *Use a gerund whenever "to" is not an infinitive marker*.

When *to* is a preposition, it is followed by **a noun or something that functions as one** (including a gerund):

> *look forward to **dinner***
>   *look forward to **the meal***
>   *look forward to **whatever we're having for dinner***
>   *look forward to **eating***

In *drive somebody to ___*, *to* is either a preposition or an infinitive marker, depending on what follows it.

When *to* is a preposition, *drive somebody to ___* is followed by **a noun or something that functions as one**:

> *drive somebody to **the edge of insanity***
>   *drive somebody to **the store***
>   *drive somebody to **wherever he or she needs to go***
>   *drive somebody to **thinking***

When *drive* is used in its sense of *compel*, *drive somebody ___* is followed by **a to-infinitive verb phrase**—the *to* infinitive marker + the base form of the verb + whatever else it might need for completion:

> *drive somebody **to leave***
>   *drive somebody **to finish dinner***
>   *drive somebody **to stop smoking***

Sometimes you have a choice; you just need to decide what you're trying to say:

> Preposition + **nominal**:
>   *Love has driven men and women to **strange extremes**.*
>   ?*Love has driven men and women to **acting strangely**.* (somewhat awkward)
>   **Love has compelled men and women to **acting strangely**.* (incorrect)
>
> Infinitive marker + **bare verb etc.**:
>   *Love has driven men and women to **act strangely**.*
>   *Love has compelled men and women to **act strangely**.*

Comment: The snag is, with _drive someone to drink_, unless one is privy to something going on deeper than the surface structure 'drink' can be **noun** OED: '3. ... Indulgence to excess in intoxicating liquor' _or_ **verb** Longman '2 ...  '[to] drink alcohol, especially regularly or too much'.

Comment: Yes, *drink* in *drive someone to drink* — the idiomatic expression — is a noun. If one wishes to argue that he or she means *compel someone to drink*, then *drink* is not a noun. Neither is it the idiomatic expression. We also say, idiomatically, *drive someone to drinking* (gerund/noun). In any case, the OP did not bring up *drink*, so I chose to not add to the confusion.

Comment: But you've not given compelling evidence that 'drive someone to drink' _**must** be using the noun intercategorial polyseme_. Farlex DoI says it's _not_. // '[the need for attention] drove her to become an actor' and '[the need for attention] drove her to acting' are both idiomatic; both 'drove her to become an actor' and 'drove her to acting' are evidenced on the Internet....

Comment: And, for instance, on [this page of Google search results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22drove+her+to%22+-%22drove+her+to+the%22+-Dallas&ei=z9tgXtrKK_O58gKn3brgDQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwia7riQl4PoAhXznFwKHaeuDtwQ8NMDegQICxA_&biw=1325&bih=736), half the examples are of the 'drive someone to V' form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure why compelling evidence for anything unrelated to the the OP's question should be provided here. We should make **_Drive [someone] to drink: noun or verb?_** its own question. As I noted, *drive to* can be followed by a nominal or a bare verb, depending on the meaning. *Drink* can be either. I believe etymological arguments for *the idiomatic expression* point to noun. Meanwhile, let context be the guide:  *He was driven to drink, then to heroin.* (noun) *He was driven to drink a glass of milk.* (verb)

Comment: 'Yes, drink in drive someone to drink — the idiomatic expression — is a noun.' is the statement that needs supporting evidence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Right, but not here in the comments of a question that has nothing to do with *drink*.

Comment: Is it not acceptable to challenge an unsupported claim that is not all that obvious?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, it's acceptable. But why here? I suggest posting a question.

Comment: Because someone may see your decent answer, think _This guy knows his stuff_, read your comment 'Yes, _drink_ in _drive someone to drink_ – the idiomatic expression – is a noun.' and take it as Gospel.

Answer (score 0):

> Long story short: Why is ‘drive somebody to’ followed by an infinitive and not a gerund as e.g. ‘look forward to?

In *to drive someone to drink*, "to drink" is **not** an infinitive; it is a preposition + a noun. Drink(n. uncountable) = alcohol; alcoholic drinks. e.g. "Drink is only sold to adults."

It is no different from "I drove him to school" or "I drove him to distraction."

Comment: How about *His violent behaviour drove her to leave home* and *His violent behaviour made her leave home*? Infinitives (full and bare, respectively) following causatives?

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat "To leave home" is an infinitive phrase - these have several functions. In this case, it answers the question "To what state did he drive her?" Compare - "He drove her mad." Have a look at https://englishsentences.com/infinitive-phrase/

Comment: My point was that in *drive [someone] to ____*, *to* is not always a preposition. *Drive someone to drink*, where *drink* is a noun preceded by a preposition, is an idiom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question is concerned with a slightly different aspect: As you have mentioned the ‘leave’ in ‘violent behaviour drove her to leave home’ is an infinitive. I am wondering: why don’t we use a gerund (‘… to leaving home’) as e.g. in ‘she looks forward to leaving home’?

Comment: The [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drove+him+to) analyses 'to drink' here as a to-infinitive: **drive (one) to (do something)** ... 
_To motivate, compel, or impel one to do something._
... The desire to set a good example for my kids drove me to finally complete my college degree. / 
The stress of this job is going to drive me to drink. //// I'm not sure I agree with this, but at least it's an attempt at a supporting reference.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth The Farlex dictionary is wrong as far as the "to drink " example is concerned, unless the stress of the job made him thirsty. "I drove the horse to the river to drink (inf.)." "Breeding horses drove me to drink." And OED: **3. specific  a. Intoxicating alcoholic beverage. Hence in various phrases: Indulgence to excess in intoxicating liquor; habits of intemperance, drunkenness. in drink: intoxicated, drunk**.: 1887   H. R. Tedder in Dictionary of National Biography IX. 330/2   *With advancing years Caulfield took to drink.*

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drink) also has ‘drink’ as a noun for ‘**excessive consumption** of alcoholic beverages.’ Interestingly enough in their example ‘he took to drink when his business failed’ we also see a ‘to drink’…

Comment: Piling up examples showing that 'drink' is also a noun proves nothing. I can add << **drink** [V] [intransitive] to drink alcohol, especially regularly or too much >> [[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/drink)]. [So far] only the Farlex DoI pronounces on **the actual usage involved here**, though as I say, I'd like to see an authority stating the opposite.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth " I'd like to see an authority stating the opposite." -- See my comment above and the quote from the OED.

Comment: This answer (perhaps unconsciously) rather refers to the comment by Hot Licks (to the original post) than to the original post. Therefore, the battle here is kind of attacking and defending of a strawman (as related to the original post).